# C# .NET VS Setup Project, file added to Program Files (x86) gone after user switch

Tags: c#, .net, virtualstore

I have a C# .NET project and a VS Setup Project to install it. Inside the C# .NET project I have System.Configuration.Install.Installer subclass. The Installer subclass needs to write a file inside the "c:\Program Files (x86)\AppName" folder and this file will have content from a parameter asked for in the installer.
This all works great until the user decides to log out and another user logs on.
Then the file disappears and the program does not work. I need the file to be saved in the app's Program Files (x86) folder permanently and it should not be removed.

I read that this is related to Windows Vista and later have something called a Virtual Store for Program Files but I don't understand how I can bypass this so I can really place a file there. In most cases, it would be incorrect to store in this directory, but in this case, I really need to. It is a setting made in the Installer and should be there. It is the correct place.

Below is the code of the Installer class

**EDIT**:
Now I just found something I did not notice before. Seem like when I log in to the other user, the installer is executed again **immediately after login**, but now there is no Context.Parameters["ActivationCode"] this time. IS this expected? What is actually starting the installer? Does it do this for every user? Since it fails I guess it will rollback and that removes the files.

```
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer {
    public ProjectInstaller() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver) {
        base.Install(stateSaver);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.Parameters["ActivationCode"])) {
            throw new InstallException("Missing activation code!");
        }

        string installDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]);
        File.WriteAllText(installDir + "\\ActivationCode.txt", Context.Parameters["ActivationCode"]);
    }

    public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState) {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);

        try {
            string installDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]);
            File.Delete(installDir + "\\ActivationCode.txt");
        }
        catch (Exception) {
        }

    }

    public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState) {
        base.Rollback(savedState);

        try {
            string installDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]);
            File.Delete(installDir + "\\ActivationCode.txt");
        }
        catch (Exception) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the installer run elevated as Administrator?

Comment: @RunCMD Yes it should be elevated to Admin during the install I presume.

Comment: Are you saying that the installer only installs your activation code? If so, how is your application installed? Also, if that's the case, what part of the installation process triggers the activation code install? Are you installing for All Users, or for Current User? Are you saying that the activation code installer runs on login, or when the new user clicks the program link? There is too much information missing from this question.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I have updated the question. There is a step in the installation where you can fill in the activation code. I instruct all users to always install for "All Users" however both options are in the installation, dont know how to remove the other item. And the installer runs automatically after login with new user, but in this case since the user does not see the install steps activation code is empty. Hope it is clear now?